# Кириллица в CGI

Tags: python, iis, cgi

Пытаюсь подружить IIS 6.0 и питон. Пишу скрипт

```
print 'Status: 200 OK'
print 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251'
print
print '<html><head><title>Python test</title></head>'
print '<body><h1>Test!</h1></body>'
print '</html>'
```

Все работает, страница отображается.

Пытаюсь вывести русские буквы (файл сохранен в win1251)

```
print 'Status: 200 OK'
print 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251'
print
print '<html><head><title>Python test</title></head>'
print '<body><h1>Тест!</h1></body>'
print '</html>'
```

получаю ошибку

> **Ошибка CGI**
>
> Указанное приложение CGI не возвратило полный набор заголовков HTTP.

Чего я не учитываю?

В логе IIS такие строчки (на удачный и неудачный вызов)

```
2018-12-28 16:17:36 W3SVC1 192.168.1.1 GET /hg/test.cgi - 80 - 192.168.1.2 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+6.2;+WOW64;+Trident/6.0;+.NET4.0E;+.NET4.0C;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.0.30729) 200 0 0
2018-12-28 16:19:33 W3SVC1 192.168.1.1 GET /hg/test.cgi - 80 - 192.168.1.2 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+6.2;+WOW64;+Trident/6.0;+.NET4.0E;+.NET4.0C;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.0.30729) 502 2 0
```

Comment: Питон определённо печатает ошибку в какой-то лог, но я не в курсе, где его читать в IIS

Comment: И зачем вам windows-1251, если уже лет тридцать существует utf-8?

Comment: @andreymal c utf-8 та же проблема

Comment: coding: utf-8 в первую строчку файла, как вы сами и написали в комментарии. А лучше просто установите третий питон, так как второй официально помрёт через год

Comment: @andreymal Это я пытаюсь Mercurial поднять. А он на питоне 2.6

Comment: Ох беда. Что ж, придётся через год считать Mercurial тоже дохлым)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первой строчкой скрипта добавьте

```
# -*- coding: cp1251 -*-
```

и убедитесь, что текст исходного кода действительно в этой кодировке. А ещё лучше используйте utf-8 вместо cp1251.

Comment: С utf-8 та же проблема `# -*- coding: utf8 -*-` ее исправляет (если файл пересохранить в utf-8)